# Javascript misses some clicks

Tags: javascript, calculator, addeventlistener

Hi I'm new to javascript, and trying to make a basic calculator

I started with the add button

When I run the code sometimes I have to click on the `btn-add` button twice or 3 times to display the result and the calculations when the number of digits of the input is greater than the previous result
Any ideas?

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-add')
const userInput = document.querySelector('#input-number')
const currentResultOutput = document.querySelector('#current-result')
const currentCalculationOutput = document.querySelector('#current-calculation')
let currentResult = 0
let currentDescription

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addFn)

function addFn() {
  currentDescription = ` ${currentResult} + ${userInput.value} `
  currentResult += Number(userInput.value)
  outputResult(currentResult, currentDescription)
}

function outputResult(result, text) {
  currentResultOutput.innerHTML = result
  currentCalculationOutput.innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<section id="calculator">
  <input type="number" id="input-number" st />
  <div id="calc-actions">
    <button type="button" id="btn-add">+</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-subtract">-</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-multiply">*</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-divide">/</button>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="results">
  <h2 id="current-calculation">0</h2>
  <h2>Result: <span id="current-result">0</span></h2>
</section>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and spelled `ParseInt` `parseInt` and the code seems to work just fine

Comment: Welcome :) I can't reproduce it here. Your code seems to work as expected ‍♂️ Can you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @mplungjan parseInt is right

Comment: @linthertoss I changed his ParseInt to parseInt when I made the snippet

Comment: still doesn't. I changed ```parseInt``` to ```Number``` yet I'm having the same problem

Comment: Not in the code you posted. You are missing something

Comment: Works with `Number` too. The code as posted here works

Answer (score 0):

it's an issue with the laptop mouse lmaoo, sorry guys

Comment: Please delete the question then

Answer (score -1):

please replace this one

```
function addFn() {
  currentDescription = ` ${currentResult} + ${userInput.value} `
  currentResult += ParseInt(userInput.value)
  outputResult(currentResult, currentDescription)
}
```

with this code

```
function addFn() {
  currentDescription = ` ${currentResult} + ${userInput.value} `
  currentResult += parseInt(userInput.value)
  outputResult(currentResult, currentDescription)
}
```

Comment: Already fixed when I made him the snippet. Also explained in the comments to the question